# Get struct field tag using Go reflect package

Tags: reflection, struct, go

Is it possible to reflect on a field of a struct, and get a reference to its tag values?

For example:

```
type User struct {
    name    string `json:name-field`
    age     int
}
// ...
user := &User{"John Doe The Fourth", 20}
getStructTag(user.name)
// ...
func getStructTag(i interface{}) string{
   //get tag from field
   
}
```

From what I can see, the usual way to do this is to range over `typ.NumField()`, and then call `field.Tag.Get("tagname")`.

However, in my use-case, it would be much better to not have to pass the whole struct in.

Comment: You can also get fields by name. What's wrong with passing the struct? If you don't pass the struct, how do you intend to get the type?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You don't need to pass in the whole struct, but passing in the value of one of the fields is not sufficient.

In your example `user.name` field is just a `string` - the reflect package will have no way of correlating that back to the original struct.

Instead, you need to pass around the `reflect.StructField` for the given field:

```
field, ok := reflect.TypeOf(user).Elem().FieldByName("name")
…
tag = string(field.Tag)
```

Note: we use `Elem` above because `user` is a pointer to a struct.

[You can play with an example here.](https://play.golang.org/p/0SJT8I6gGR5)

Comment: Your playground example had bugs, which I fixed for those who do not know how: https://play.golang.org/p/0SJT8I6gGR5

Comment: What if I don't want to pass the entire struct but just get the value of a specific field? reflect.TypeOf(user.Name).Elem().

Answer (score 10):

Modifying the above answer can give value of a specific tag

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name_field"`
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    user := &User{"John Doe The Fourth", 20}

    field, ok := reflect.TypeOf(user).Elem().FieldByName("Name")
    if !ok {
        panic("Field not found")
    }
    fmt.Println(getStructTag(field, "json")) //name_field
}

func getStructTag(f reflect.StructField, tagName string) string {
    return f.Tag.Get(tagName)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Sb0i7za5Uow

Answer (score 3):

Clean way to list all tags from a struct (using external lib).

External lib: https://github.com/fatih/structs

Example: https://go.dev/play/p/C_yXMdbFYAq

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/fatih/structs"
)

type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name_field"`
    Age  int    `json:"age_field"`
}

func main() {
    user := &User{}
    fields := structs.Fields(user)

    for _, field := range fields {
        tag := field.Tag("json")
        fmt.Println(tag)
    }
}
```

Result:

```
name_field
age_field
```