# How to use Go interface{} for generic gorm insert

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to setup a Go base module that can allow other modules to perform CRUD data to database via GORM.

1. The base module defines a `Create` method that takes a `ServiceInput` struct as input and performs the insertion logic using GORM.
2. The session module (as an example of base client module) defines a `Session` struct to represent a session and a `CreateSess` method to create a new session. Inside `CreateSess`, it creates a new session instance, prepares a `ServiceInput` struct with the session data and the table name, and then calls the `base.Create` method to perform the insertion. The GORM database instance (db) is defined and initiated as a global variable.

I have omited some codes that defines the req CdRequest param which has not participated at the create process. It only used for post create process.

Starting with Create, on the base I have:

```
package base

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var db = Conn()

// ServiceInput struct represents the input for the Create method
type ServiceInput struct {
    ServiceModel interface{}
    ModelName    string
    DocName      string
    Cmd          Cmd
    DSource      int
}

func Create(req CdRequest, servInput ServiceInput) CdResponse {
    logger.LogInfo("Starting BaseModule::CdCreate()...")
    logger.LogInfo("Base::CbCreate()/servInput.ServiceModel:" + fmt.Sprint(servInput.ServiceModel))
    result := db.Table(servInput.ModelName).Create(&servInput.ServiceModel)
    if result.Error != nil {
        respMsg = "Could not create " + servInput.ModelName
        logger.LogInfo("Base::CbCreate()/respMsg:" + respMsg)
        logger.LogError("Base::CbCreate():" + fmt.Sprint(result.Error))
        var appState = CdAppState{false, respMsg, nil, "", ""}
        var appData = RespData{Data: nil, RowsAffected: 0, NumberOfResult: 0}
        resp := CdResponse{AppState: appState, Data: appData}
        return resp
    }
    //...weeded off some codes below this for the sake of clariry
    resp := CdResponse{}
    var appState = CdAppState{true, respMsg, jsonResult, "", ""}
    var appData = RespData{Data: jsonResult, RowsAffected: 0, NumberOfResult: 1}
    resp = CdResponse{AppState: appState, Data: appData}
    return resp
}
```

As an example, I have started with session module which is set up as below:

```
package session

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "time"
    "base_module_path/base"
)

// Session model
type Session struct {
    SessionId     uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CurrentUserId uint
    CdToken       string
    Active        bool
    Ttl           uint
    AccTime       time.Time
    StartTime     time.Time
    DeviceNetId   datatypes.JSON
    ConsumerGuid  string
}

func CreateSess(req base.CdRequest) base.CdResponse {
    logger.LogInfo("Starting UserModule::Session::SessNew()...")

    // Create a new session instance
    cdToken := uuid.New()
    sess := Session{
        CdToken:       cdToken.String(),
        StartTime:     time.Now(),
        AccTime:       time.Now(),
        Active:        true,
        ConsumerGuid:  "",
        CurrentUserId: 1000,
        DeviceNetId:   nil,
    }
    servInput := base.ServiceInput{}
    servInput.ModelName = "session"
    servInput.ServiceModel = sess
    resp := base.Create(req, servInput)
    return resp
}
```

Below is the reported error:

```
2024/03/25 08:45:03 /media/emp-06/disk-02/projects/test-projects/cd-core/sys/base/b.go:226 unsupported data
[0.553ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `session` (`current_user_id`,`cd_token`,`active`,`ttl`,`acc_time`,`start_time`,`device_net_id`,`consumer_guid`) VALUES 
[INFO] Base::Create()/respMsg:Could not create session
[ERROR] Base::Create():unsupported data
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to do the type assertion with switch case something like below
This is the example I tried in local ,hopefully it works

This solution works but you have to keep your table name columns same as your struct field names

```
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

// ServiceInput struct represents the input for the Create method
type ServiceInput struct {
    ServiceModel interface{}
    ModelName    string
    DocName      string
    DSource      int
}

type Session struct {
    SessionId     uint   `gorm:"session_id,primaryKey"`
    CurrentUserId uint   `gorm:"current_user_id"`
    CdToken       string `gorm:"cd_token"`
    Active        bool   `gorm:"active"`
    Ttl           uint   `gorm:"ttl"`
    ConsumerGuid  string `gorm:"consumer_guid"`
}

func getStructTag(f reflect.StructField, tagName string) string {
    return strings.Split(f.Tag.Get(tagName), ",")[0]
}

func Create(servInput ServiceInput, db *gorm.DB) {
    structValue := reflect.ValueOf(servInput.ServiceModel)
    record := make(map[string]interface{})
    for i := 0; i < structValue.NumField(); i++ {
        field := structValue.Type().Field(i)
        fieldValue := structValue.Field(i)
        record[getStructTag(field, "gorm")] = fieldValue.Interface()
    }

    result := db.Table(servInput.ModelName).Create(record)
    if result.Error != nil {
        log.Fatal(result.Error)
    }

}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("mydatabase.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    sv := ServiceInput{
        ServiceModel: Session{
            SessionId:     1,
            CurrentUserId: 2,
            CdToken:       "hello",
            Active:        true,
        },
        ModelName: "sessions",
    }

    Create(sv, db)

}
```

Comment: Hi, note that in the case I have mentioned, the call is made from session module which invokes Create() in base module. The base module should never anticipate which list of client module names it can get to serve. So the switch case will not work.  The application is being built to allow extensibility where new module names cannot be known at the time of development.  Session is just a sample client.

Comment: Have updated my answe ,Try this out ,hopefully it works @goremo

Comment: Thanks @Shubham. I have tested your modification. It seem very close but  the names of columns are replaced by Model struct names  output:  Error 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'AccTime' in 'field list'
[0.635ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `session` (`AccTime`,`Active`,`CdToken`,`ConsumerGuid`,`CurrentUserId`,`DeviceNetId`,`SessionId`,`StartTime`,`Ttl`) VALUES ('2024-03-25 19:09:24.68',true,'d536b837-c902-450f-996c-cd8d6aa228df','',1000,NULL,0,'2024-03-25 19:09:24.68',0)
2024/03/25 19:09:24 Error 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'AccTime' in 'field list'

Comment: hmm that can be resolved too .

Comment: It is narrowing down...but some compiler error, could be some minute issue...also trying from my end: getStructTag(field, "gorm") (no value) used as valuecompilerTooManyValues
func getStructTag(field reflect.StructField, s string)

Comment: you have to give your model a tag ,then only it can do .As go being compiled languages what you are trying to achieve is nearly impossible.

Comment: I already have just as in your example. The clue you have given seem very promising and I am working on it. It seem to me this is so doable...it is just that we are not yet there.

Comment: I have eventually succeeded by followinig your principle and making use of "github.com/fatih/structs" to get the fields correctly...usinig hints from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507033/get-struct-field-tag-using-go-reflect-package. I will clean the codes and see how I can share the result. I have also up voted your answer